# loading time_stamp format using sqlldr

Tags: sql-loader

I have the following time_stamp data in my csv file:
`CREATE_DATE = 17-SEP-14 03.26.26.000000000 PM`

I try the following statement when loading with SQL*Loader:
`(CREATE_DATE "to_timestamp(:CREATE_DATE,'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS AM')"`

But it fails with:
`AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your control file entry for that field should look like this:

```
CREATE_DATE TIMESTAMP "dd-MON-yy hh.mi.ss.ff9 PM"
```